# Boolean value changing button click

Tags: java

What would be the most simple solution each time a user presses a certain button the bool value changes? The only thing in my button action listener would be a call to a certain method for example Method1();
Or would working with a int be a more viable solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
buttonFlag = ! buttonFlag;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a flag variable on the fields in your class.

Example:

```
private boolean bottonFlag = false.
```

in your method do:

```
bottonFlag = bottonFlag == true ? false : true; // this is to switch between true and false
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a JToggleButton or JCheckBox for this case.  It would be more natural to the user and either component can store it's state without declaring any further booleans.

E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ToggleButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JLabel result = new JLabel("Hit the button!");

        final JToggleButton switchButton = new JToggleButton("Switch");
        switchButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                result.setText("" + switchButton.isSelected());
            }
        } );

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        p.add(switchButton);
        p.add(result);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is exactly what your looking for!! Hope it helps.

```
    private boolean booly; 

private class WinkAction implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {

        if (!booly){
            booly = true; 

        }else {
            booly = false;


        }

    }
}
```